# Change font list in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Has anyone tried to add a font to the font dropdown in Content Builder? We would like to add Helvetica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFMC Support confirmed this is not an option.

Comment: Is there an official blog post or other webpage on the subject, or some rationale included in their reply to you which you could add to this answer?

Comment: No...they just responded that this is not possible and if it is important enough we should promote it at the IdeaExchange.